# Как сделать такую границу(ломаные линии)?

Tags: html, css

Привет!
Как сделать такие границы(ломаные линии)?
[image]

[image]

Comment: А почему бы не картинкой?

Answer (score 1):

Можно попробовать с помощью SVG нарисовать либо HTML5 Canvas.

Comment: Похоже, автор спрашивает, как сделать это средствами CSS.